database "template0" is not currently accepting connections
i got the following error
database "template0" is not currently accepting connections
How to vaccum it?
Thanks
UPDATE
i got the following yesterday
postgres=> select * from public.test;
WARNING:  database "template0" must be vacuumed within 33781829 transactions
HINT:  To avoid a database shutdown, execute a database-wide VACUUM in that database.
You might also need to commit or roll back old prepared transactions, or drop stale replication slots.

I got the following now:
postgres=> drop table public.test;
ERROR:  database is not accepting commands to avoid wraparound data loss in database "template0"
HINT:  Stop the postmaster and vacuum that database in single-user mode.
You might also need to commit or roll back old prepared transactions, or drop stale replication slots.

postgres=> SELECT datname, age(datfrozenxid) FROM pg_database;
  datname  |    age     
-----------+------------
 template0 | 2143523316
 template1 | 2143523316
 postgres  | 2143523316

